# C++ CMake Project: Recipe for target 'main_app' failed

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I am trying to build a CMake project, below is a sample code of what I am trying to do.

I have two header files I am developing and I want to call a member function in class **Processor** from class **Loader** using the thread header. Here is the code, along with the CMake, and the error message I got after running the `make` command.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(c-plus-assignment)
## C++11 Flags
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
add_compile_options(-pthread)
add_compile_options(-Werror=return-type)                   # error on missing return type
add_compile_options(-Werror=format)                        # error on wrong printf formats
add_compile_options(-Werror=parentheses)                   # error when using ambiguous syntax
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)


add_executable(main_app
        main.cpp
        src/Processor.cpp
        src/Loader.cpp
        src/Logger.cpp)
```

Loader.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <c-assignment/Processor.hpp>

using namespace std;
class Loader
{
private:
  Processor *Processor_obj; // creating an object out of the Processor class
  std::thread t1;
  Processor boo;


public:
    Loader();
    ~Loader();
    void thr(int time);
    string usr_input;
    void read_usr_input(void);
};
```

Processor.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Processor
{
public:

    bool status;       //status of processing true = free, false = busy
    float wait_amount; //variable to store the random generated float
    Processor();
    void process(string);
};
```

Loader.cpp

```
#include <c-assignment/Loader.hpp>
#include <c-assignment/Logger.hpp>
#include <c-assignment/Processor.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

Loader::Loader()
{
  Processor_obj = new Processor(); // creating an object out of the Processor class
}
Loader::~Loader()
{
  t1.join();
}
void Loader::read_usr_input(void)
{

  std::cout << "Please enter a command" << '\n';
  std::cin >> Loader::usr_input;
  if (Processor_obj->status == true) //check if the Processor is busy or not
  {
    if (Loader::usr_input == "fc" || Loader::usr_input == "out")
    {
      //Processor_obj->process(Loader::usr_input);
      Loader::t1 = std::thread(&Processor::process,Loader::boo,Loader::usr_input);
    }
    //else if (){}
    //else if (){}
    else
    {
    std::cout << "Unknown command" << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n' << "you entered the command" << Loader::usr_input << '\n';
  }
  else {std::cout << "Processor class is busy" << '\n';}
}
```

Processor.cpp

```
#include <c-assignment/Processor.hpp>
#include <c-assignment/Logger.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

Processor::Processor()
{
  Processor::status = true;
}
void Processor::process(string usr_input)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  Processor::wait_amount = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * (3.00f - 1.00f) + 1.00f;
  std::cout << "waiting time is" << (Processor::wait_amount)*1000 << "milliseconds" << '\n';
  Processor::status = false;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((int)(Processor::wait_amount)*1000));
  Processor::status = true;
  std::cout << "/Processed/" << '\n';
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <c-assignment/Processor.hpp>
#include <c-assignment/Loader.hpp>
#include <c-assignment/Logger.hpp>

int main()
{

    while (true) {
        Processor a;
        Loader b;
        Logger c;
        //a.process("rfc");
        b.read_usr_input();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output when I run `make`:

```
    [ 20%] Linking CXX executable main_app
CMakeFiles/main_app.dir/src/Loader.cpp.o: In function `std::thread::thread<void (Processor::*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >), Processor&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(void (Processor::*&&)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >), Processor&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
Loader.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IM9ProcessorFvNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEJRS1_RS7_EEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IM9ProcessorFvNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEJRS1_RS7_EEEOT_DpOT0_]+0xb4): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/main_app.dir/build.make:172: recipe for target 'main_app' failed
make[2]: *** [main_app] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main_app.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_app.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important section of your `make` output is the linker error: `undefined reference to 'pthread_create'`. This indicates that the linker cannot find the definition for this pthread function. You have not *linked* the pthread libraries in your CMake, so you should try doing that to fix your error. After your CMake call to `add_executable()`, add the line:

```
target_link_libraries(main_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

This assumes that your call to `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` correctly found the pthread libraries and populated the imported target [`Threads::Threads`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html). If that doesn't work, you can also try linking directly to the `pthread` library instead with the following:

```
target_link_libraries(main_app PRIVATE pthread)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that really solved the issue.

I am facing another problem that I don't know where to put the t1.join(); where it should be some where because I am running the program infinitly.

if run once and then give me "terminate called without an active exception"

if you have any clue please help